# Are two tables (native, external) always required in Hive for querying a DynamoDB table from AWS EMR?

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

Are two hive tables (native, external) always required for querying a DynamoDB table from an AWS EMR?

I have created a native hive table (CTAS, create table as select) using an hive external table that was mapped to a DynamoDB table. My  (read) query times against external tables are slow and it uses up the read throughput versus native table are fast and read throughput is not consumed.

My questions:

1. Is this a standard practice/best practice i.e., create an external table mapped to a dynamodb table and then create a CTAS and query against CTAS for all read query use cases?
2. Where or how GSI's on dynamodb come into picture on hive side of things?  Toward this curiosity I have tried to map my external hive table column to dynamodb GSI and some what expectedly saw NULLs.
   So, back to #2 question was wondering how are GSI's used with a native or external hive table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is no.
However, from my observation if a hive native table data is  backed (CTAS) by hive external table that is referencing a DynamoDb table:  Read data is not accounted if you are querying hive native table from EMR.  If you to take into account the periodic update (refresh data) of hive native table.